# Stop making an extension reload when opening new page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Hello everyone and thanks for reading,

**My Extension**

I'm making a chrome extension for a school project. It's an extension that helps you with copying stuff from the internet and putting it in one file.

How it works is: you select text, press a button and it adds it selected text to your selection. You can do this a couple of times on a page. After you selected all the text you wanted, you press enter and it downloads it.

**The Problem**

So at the moment, the extension works fine but **only** for the page you're visiting at that moment. When you open a new page or browse to a different website, the extension seems te get reloaded because the previous selection is gone. Let's say you have 2 pages. On page 1 you select some text and add it to your selection, now you go to page 2 and select some more text and add it to your selection and press enter to download it. When you download it, the only text you get is the text from page 2.

How can  I stop this?

**The Code**

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

function download(data, filename, type) {
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: type});
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // IE10+
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
    else { // Others
        var a = document.createElement("a"),
                url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }, 0);
    }
}

var test = readTextFile("strings.txt");
var inhoud = "";
var raised = false;
var lastUrl = "";


// Hallo meneer Hemert (Als u dit leest);

  document.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      raised = true;
  }
  });

  document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if(raised ==true) {
      inhoud += "\n";
      inhoud += "\n";
      inhoud += "Bron: ";
      inhoud += document.URL;
      lastUrl = document.URL;
      download(test, "tekst.rtf");
      raised = false;
    }
  });



  document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode == 18) {
    if (window.getSelection() == "") {
          console.log("prank gaat fout");
    }
    else {

      inhoud += getSelectionText();
      if (document.URL == lastUrl) {
        console.log("hallo");
      } else {

      }
    }
  }
  });

  // Deze functie leest de tekst uit een tekstbestand.
  // Dit is handig zodat de plugin kan werken op elke pagina

function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                alert(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

Please don't cringe at it, I'm seventeen and learning...

Comment: It would help if you post your current code

Comment: @RamonMarques Ok, thanks for commenting. I'll get the code from my other laptop and place it here, should take about 1 minute.

Comment: See examples for chrome.storage.local to share the data between tabs.

Comment: Code added,  @RamonMarques

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for commenting this. I think this may be what I need. Could you give me an example of how I save a string with that?

Comment: When I said "see examples" I meant "use google search". It's much more convenient because you can look at different use cases.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].